# No line break after while-statement with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I want to configure clang-format (version 14.0.6) that it leaves single-line while-statement without adding a line break for the trailing semicolon (C++):

For example, clang-format should just leave a "one-liner" as it is:

```
while (checkWaitCondition() != true);
```

But unfortunately clang-format adds by default a line break (plus an indentation of 4 spaces):

```
while (checkWaitCondition() != true)
    ;
```

I tried the options `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` + `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine`, but without any impact...

Does anyone have an idea how I can prevent, that clang-format breaks the semicolon into the next line?

I use this *.clang-format* configuration file:

```
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
IndentWidth: 4
Language: Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeComma
ColumnLimit: 120
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000000
SortIncludes: false
DeriveLineEnding: false
UseCRLF: false
```

Comment: One "fix" that I would suppose to work is adding braces to your loop.

Comment: Given `while (true);` is undefined behaviour it doesn't surprise me that clang format doesn't format it in the way you expect

Comment: @gerum: Thanks, replacing the semicolon with `{}` would help to remove the break, but I would prefer to keep the semicolon

Comment: Since there is `do {} while(true);` (rarely used), I would prefer to force `{}` by coding standard instead semicolon at the end dummy `while` loop to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason, why clang-format ignored the settings for `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` and `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine`: I had another `.clang-format` file in a lower directory, which overwrote my test-configuration...

With both flags set to true, the format works as expected, with the following setting in the `.clang-format` file:

```
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
```

Produces the following format:

`while (checkWaitCondition() != true) { }`

But for my purpose, I want to use the `continue` statement from now, to improve the readability:

`while (checkWaitCondition() != true) { continue; }`